# IIS7.5 URL Rewrite, with or without trailing slash

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm using IIS7.5 and have a rule for rewriting a URL...

The rule is:
    ^trade/new_products/page([^/]+)/?.*$

But, this is only working when I don't include a slash - e.g.
    http://www.website.com/trade/new_products/page1

I'd like it to also work with
    http://www.toppstiles.co.uk/trade/new_products/page1/

Can I do this or do I need a separate rule?

Answer (score 0):

This group ([^/]+) is catching everything but slash. If your page is only numeric you can try this one:

```
^trade/new_products/page([0-9]+)/?.*$
```

If not, you can use the non greedy modifier on the multiplier(+?):

```
^trade/new_products/page([^/]+?)/?.*$
```

Comment: ^trade/new_products/page([^/]+?)/?.*$ doesn't seem to work... it's doing the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - the rule was working as expected - it was another issue that was causing my problem!